# semantic_form_for's submit button cancels the input field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm trying to create a form with active-admin in a new page with this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Attach Logger" do
  content do
    semantic_form_for :project do |f|
      f.inputs do
        f.input :owner, as: :select, collection: Logger.where(:tested => false)
      end
      f.actions
    end
  end
end
```

but I only see the button in the HTML produced without the select tag:

```
<div id="active_admin_content" class="without_sidebar">
  <div id="main_content_wrapper">
    <div id="main_content">
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/activeadmin/attach_logger" class="formtastic project" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
          <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
          <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="YjpVXb+RYu6xX7IggTQys77bsS98ChuJU02vDZeZR+s=" />
        </div>
        <fieldset class="actions">
          <ol>
            <li class="action input_action " id="project_submit_action">
              <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Project" />
            </li>
          </ol>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I comment out the `f.actions` I can see the select tag in the HTML:

```
<div id="active_admin_content" class="without_sidebar">
  <div id="main_content_wrapper">
    <div id="main_content">
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/activeadmin/attach_logger" class="formtastic project" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
          <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
          <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="YjpVXb+RYu6xX7IggTQys77bsS98ChuJU02vDZeZR+s=" />
        </div>
          <fieldset class="inputs">
            <ol>
              <li class="select input required" id="project_owner_input">
                <label class="label" for="project_owner">
                  Owner
                  <abbr title="required">
                  *
                  </abbr>
                </label>
                <select id="project_owner" name="project[owner]">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="6142">#&lt;Logger:0x0000000b528ab8&gt;</option>
                  <option value="6143">#&lt;Logger:0x00000002b023e8&gt;</option>
                  <option value="6146">#&lt;Logger:0x00000002b04c38&gt;</option>
                </select>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

how can I get them in the same form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use [`active_admin_form_for`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/cc812586f7d659f0f2bf61e7f941a4fbf9e3420b/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/form_helper.rb) instead of `semantic_form_for`.

```
active_admin_form_for :project do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :owner, as: :select, collection: Logger.where(:tested => false)
  end
  f.actions
end
```

The reason is due to how [Arbre](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre) buffers content versus Rails' approach to buffering content. Here ActiveAdmin provides a wrapper to help with that issue via its `active_admin_form_for` form helper.